# Creating Array Objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm quite new to Java and had a little problem concerning arrays. In an exercise given one had to create a class named "Exam" with a method "addExam". Now I tried to solve the problem but only got to the definition of the cass, the instance variables and the method heading. The rest I looked up in the solution and it looked like:

```
public class Exam{
private int numberOfExams=15;
private Exam[]exams = new Exam[numberOfExams];

public void addExam(Exam exam){
exams[numberOfExams] = exam;
numberOfExams++;
```

So now to my question: When I assign "exam" to the array exams in the method addExam, is a new object created here? And when yes, why aren't bracktes and the "new operator" used? This question leads to a more general one: I know that arrays are of a class type, do they now create array objects or variables of that array type?

I really need some help!

Comment: That looks like an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`... I mean, creating an array of size **15**, then indexing to `[15]` and incrementing? That should crash on the first call. An array of size `15` has indices from `0...14`.

Comment: Also consider using a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instend of an array. They offer much more flexibility.

Comment: indeed, `List<Exam> list = new ArrayList<Exam>(); list.add(new Exam()); ...`

Comment: thanks! That seems more efficient

Answer (score 3):

```
public void addExam(Exam exam){
exams[numberOfExams] = exam;
```

No. No new object created, what ever the object passed here assigned to the 0th element of your array.

The actual place of creating new object is the place where addExam method called. Something like

```
Exam exam = new Exam();
// do something
addExam(exam);
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I assign "exam" to the array exams in the method addExam, is a new object created here?

**No**. A reference to the existing `Exam` instance will be added to the array. So, you will have 2 references to the same instance of `Exam`

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an "exam" to the array, it doesn't create a new object. It merely stores the reference of an existing object in the array.

If I understand your second question, when you create an array with a call such as `Exam[] exams = new Exam[numberOfExams];` you create an object that contains enough space for `numberOfExams` references to `Exam` objects.

BTW, `exams[numberOfExams] = exam;` would give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since your array has `numberOfExams` elements, so the valid indices are from 0 to `numberOfExams-1`.